# Reshaping tables from long to wide format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, reshape

| set | inst | ind | color_Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 70 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 60 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 50 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 30 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 66 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 35 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 28 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 90 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 47 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 23 |

I have data frame looks like this above and I want to convert this to:

| ind | set | inst_0 | inst_1 | inst_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 70 | 60 | 50 |
| 1 | 1 | 30 | 20 | 66 |
| 2 | 1 | 35 | 22 | 28 |
| 0 | 2 | 90 | 47 | 23 |
| 1 | 2 | .. | .. | .. |
| 2 | 2 | .. | .. | .. |

How can I do this transform? I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you so much!

I have tried some things but did not really work.I have to do the change based on two columns information and that was confusing me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data.table**

```r
df <- read.table(text = "set    inst    ind color_Blue
1   0   0   70
1   0   1   60
1   0   2   50
1   1   0   30
1   1   1   20
1   1   2   66
2   0   0   35
2   0   1   22
2   0   2   28
2   1   0   90
2   1   1   47
2   1   2   23", header = T)

library(data.table)
dcast(
  data = setDT(df),
  formula = inst + set ~ paste0("inst_", ind),
  value.var = "color_Blue"
)
#>    inst set inst_0 inst_1 inst_2
#> 1:    0   1     70     60     50
#> 2:    0   2     35     22     28
#> 3:    1   1     30     20     66
#> 4:    1   2     90     47     23
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr` for reshaping.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = color_Blue, names_prefix = 'inst_')

# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#     set  inst inst_0 inst_1 inst_2
#   <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1     1     0     70     60     50
# 2     1     1     30     20     66
# 3     2     0     35     22     28
# 4     2     1     90     47     23
```

###### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
set inst    ind color_Blue
1   0   0   70
1   0   1   60
1   0   2   50
1   1   0   30
1   1   1   20
1   1   2   66
2   0   0   35
2   0   1   22
2   0   2   28
2   1   0   90
2   1   1   47
2   1   2   23", header = TRUE)
```